# why to use ref keyword for passing string parameter in function calling

Tags: c#

String is a reference type , so why we have to attach ref keyword ahead of string variable when we are passing in a function call for getting change in a main function
For ex:

```
 using System;    
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Text;

 namespace ConsoleApplication1
 {
    class Program
    {
       static void Main(string[] args)
       {
          string keyword= string.Empty;
          removeWhiteSpacetest(keyword);
          Console.WriteLine("Printing In Main");
          Console.ReadLine();
       }
    }

    private void removeWhiteSpacetest( string keyword)
    {
       string pattern = "\\s+";
       string replacement = " ";
       Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);

       //white space removal
       keyword = rgx.Replace(keyword, replacement).Trim();
    }
 }
```

so when i passed "   hotel management" output should be "hotel management" ,
But i get the same output i.e "   hotel management" rather than expected output "hotel management".

But when i uses list or some other reference type object i get the expected result i.e. "hotel management"

Comment: By Reference and by value are matters in this scenario, read this article for your convenient http://www.albahari.com/valuevsreftypes.aspx

Comment: have you ever tried to change a `System.String` object? (*hint*: it's immutable)

Comment: [Read this article by jon skeet](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/parameters.html) I believe it will answer all of your questions regarding the ref keyword. (even those you didn't think about yet :-))

Comment: also please note that: 1.) there is `String.Trim` 2.) you are replacing with whitespaces and based on your comments I think you don't *really*  want to do this

Comment: (really not salty) side note: the discussion shows once again: `ref` is **an antipattern** just like **null** - just because C# has no real understanding of tuples :P

Comment: @CarstenKönig: Why do think you that ref and null are antipatterns?

Comment: Hi @CarstenKönig i know the concept of call by value and call by reference that's only i got a difficulty to understand that string is a reference type class  than also we have to include ref keyword for getting any changes in main function but when i use any other reference type class for eg: List<> then i doesnot need to add ref keyword for getting changes in main function.If you want i will attach the demo code for this also.

Comment: @ZoharPeled I think `null` should be obvious (["The Billion Dollar Mistake"](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/Null-References-The-Billion-Dollar-Mistake-Tony-Hoare)) - a think you don't need if you have support for option/maybe/... types - and most use-cases for `ref` in .net seems to be that you want to return more than one value - a trivial thing if you have good support for tuples (as C# might get somewhere in the future)

Comment: Your link explain nothing. Also, .net framework supports tuples since version 4. I think the .Net framework developers might just know what they are doing...

Comment: @ZoharPeled you think it explains nothing, when the guy who *came up with*  the `null` value says it`s his **billion-dollar-mistake**? (Also I don't think you watched his talk yet - of course you can just google him/this sentence) - also if you want to know how to handle tuples/multiple returns in a sane way (and want to stick with .net) you should have a look at F# :P (if you want we can continue somewhere else - seems OT here)

Comment: Sorry, I don't have a full hour to view the video. I was expecting a short article. about F#, I don't know anything about this language, and don't really have the time to learn it. but anyway, you are right about one thing, it is of topic here.

Comment: @ZoharPeled in short `null` was so easy to implement that he could not withstand doing it - but by now it did cost us all so much that he sees it as his *biggest plunder* (so I guess he would never do it again) - and maybe you could learn a lot more if you would waste your time with F# instead of arguing on SO ... just saying ;)

Answer (score 0):

Update passing by reference as per comments below.

When you add the ref keyword in, you are <strike>passing by value</strike> passing a reference to the underlying value and can therefore, change the value of the data. <strike>A reference variable is like a pointer, not the value itself</strike>.

Read the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s6938f28.aspx) article.

Comment: what? by adding `ref` you are *passing by **value***? ... errr *no*

Comment: @CarstenKönig, ok. I am reading the article you posted and the msdn article but understand that it is passing the value of the variable. So, what am I missing?

Comment: I posted no article - but you are mixing up concepts - passing by value means you copy the value (what you would do with integers and other value-types) - the `ref` keyword here will make it possible to change the *reference* itself

Comment: @CarstenKönig, your explanation is well articulated. I clearly didn't clarify mine correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this has nothing to do with the parameter being immutable, nor does it have to do with the parameter being a reference type.

The reason you don't see a change is that you assign a new value to the parameter inside the function.

Parameters without the `ref` or `out` keywords are **Always passed by value.**
I know right now you are raising your eyebrows but let me explain:
A reference type parameter that is passed without the `ref` keyword is actually passing it's reference *by value*.
For more information read [this article](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/parameters.html) by [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet).

To demonstrate my claim I've created a small program that you can copy and paste to see for your self, or simply [check this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/WoTmmf).

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        String StringInput = "Input";

        List<int> ListInput = new List<int>();

        ListInput.Add(1);
        ListInput.Add(2);
        ListInput.Add(3);

        Console.WriteLine(StringInput);

        ChangeMyObject(StringInput);

        Console.WriteLine(StringInput);


        Console.WriteLine(ListInput.Count.ToString());

        ChangeMyObject(ListInput);

        Console.WriteLine(ListInput.Count.ToString());



        ChangeMyObject(ref StringInput);

        Console.WriteLine(StringInput);

        ChangeMyObject(ref ListInput);

        Console.WriteLine(ListInput.Count.ToString());



    }

    static void ChangeMyObject(String input)
    {

        input = "Output";
    }

    static void ChangeMyObject(ref String input)
    {

        input = "Output";
    }


    static void ChangeMyObject(List<int> input)
    {

        input = new List<int>();
    }

    static void ChangeMyObject(ref List<int> input)
    {

        input = new List<int>();
    }


}
```

The output of this program is this:

```
Input
Input
3
3
Output
0
```

Comment: Hi @Zohar thanks for the reply.but i have not clear till yet.  I have made small change in your one function which you have created above.       static void ChangeMyObject(List<int> input)
    {
        input.Add(4);
    }    and output beomes now                                                                      Input ,Input,3,4,Output,0.i.e result are reflection on main function. But static void ChangeMyObject(String input)
    {
        input = "Output";
    }  result are not reflecting in main function irrespective both are reference type.Are you getting my point?

Comment: Please avoid writing code in comments. It unreadable. use .net fiddle or edit your question to include the code.

Comment: HI @zohar sorry for that..Please have a look to my fiddler https://dotnetfiddle.net/dhEXjb. See the output.

Comment: @HimanshuJain please just stop to mutate the arguments to your functions - just return the results you want ;)

Comment: Hi @CarstenKönig i didn't get your point can you please explore it more

Comment: my point is: instead of using `ref` and try to change objects-pointers and values and stuff you should just write simple function that returns the desired result instead - like `string removeWhiteSpacetest(string input) { return input.Trim(); }` ... problems solved (please note that I am not sure what you mean with *remove Whitespace* - so this is just an example)

Comment: To answer your question, As I wrote in my answer: *A reference type parameter that is passed without the ref keyword is actually passing it's reference by value.* you should read the article I've Linked to. It's not that long and Jon explains this behavior better then me.

Comment: Hi @Carsten I already implemented  the solution which you stated in your comment , it's working fine no problem , but i tried to understand the concept of using ref keyword in our code , that's why posted above post.

Comment: ok @ZoharPeled i surely read the link which you given to me and come back to you if i found any difficulty.

Comment: @HimanshuJain no problem but then the best way would indeed be to read the article from Jon Skeet ;)