# Difference between passing a reference type and a value type as argument to a method

Tags: c#

Just got this confusion running in my mind throughout the day.
I am very much confused between reference and value type being passed to a method.

Say I have 2 classes **Class A** and **Class B** that corresponds to reference and value types respectively.

```
public Class A
{
    public static void main(string[] args)
    {
        String s = “hello”;
        String w = Changestring(s);
        String x = s;
    }

    private string Changestring(string s)
    {
        s += “Hi”;
        return s;
    }
}
```

.

```
public Class B
{
    public static void main(string[] args)
    {
        int s = 99;
        int w = Changeint(s);
        int x = s;
    }       

    private int Changeint(int s)
    {
            s += 30;
            return s;
    }
}
```

I am confused between passing a reference type(string) and value type(int) as arguments to a function.
    When I run such a program, the x for string(Reference type) is "hello" itself and x for value type is 99. Should x be "HelloHi" instead of "hello” since it is a reference type?

Please help me to clear this simple doubt.

Comment: `s += "Hi";` is shorthand for `s = s + "Hi";`. You're creating a new string, not mutating the existing one. Hence the result you're seeing

Comment: You introduces a new reference string `s` in the `ChangeString()` method, so it's different from the string `s` in the `main` method. If you wanted to mutate the existing one, you should have used `ref`.

Comment: [You might also want to read this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30369126/3094533)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Beside `Reference Type` and `Value Type`, there are `Mutable Type` and `Immutable Type`.

`Immutable` means that object cannot and will not be changed after initialization. As a result, your statement only produces new string but does not modify original string.

> s += "Hi";

The `hello` string object remains `hello`. Change is that `s` is assigned with a new object `helloHi`.

---

You are unfortunate enough using `string` as an example.

Try to use mutable types like `StringBuilder` in your example.

```
public class C
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder("hello");
        StringBuilder w = Changestring(s);
        StringBuilder x = s;
    }

    private static StringBuilder Changestring(StringBuilder s)
    {
        s.Append("Hi");
        return s;
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually, the immutability of the string has nothing to do with the result. The real reason is what Koozik wrote in his comment: `s += "Hi";` is shorthand for `s = s + "Hi";` - so the problem is the assignment of a new value to the variable passed to the method. [My answer to a similar post will prove this.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30369126/3094533)

Comment: So it means **Reference** types and **Value** types when passed as an argument to a function has the same behavior and the behavior depends only upon mutable and immutable?

Comment: @ViVi `Reference-Immutable` type behaves the same as `Value` type.

Comment: @ZoharPeled : So if I pass a string to a function as argument and do some operations with the string like trim or something, the s will store the new value or the default value itself?

Comment: @ZoharPeled `s = s + "Hi";` is correct, but I think it is wrong focus. Vivi just wished to change the string value. But of course string does not provide such method. Thus I say it is unfortunate to use string as example.

Comment: @Tommy : So in your answer, if I don't return s from Changestring() method, is the behavior still the same? I mean will w still be "hellohi" and x be "hello" ?

Comment: @ViVi since `StringBuilder` is `Reference-Mutable`, it is the only object and is being changed. All `s`, `w` and `x` point to the same `helloHi` modified StringBuilder object. Not returning variable in method does not change this fact.

Comment: @ViVi That has to do with Immutability - you can't change an existing string, so every method you can apply on a string will actually create a new string. So, `s.Trim()` will not change the value of `s`, but return a new string that is the result of the trimming action.

Answer (score 2):

First to know, passing by value **doesn't** change initial variable value, where passing by reference **also** changes initial variable value referenced by method.

By default `int` treated as value type, thus it is passed by value. However, a `String` even declared as a class (reference type), it is immutable by default with `sealed` modifier, thus treated as passing by value and adding new characters just create new instance of `String`, not changing current one.

By adding `ref` keyword you can change int behavior to passing-by-reference:

```
public Class B
{
    public static void main(string[] args)
    {
        int s = 99;
        int w = Changeint(s); // w has changed
        int x = s; // s has also changed
    }       

    private int Changeint(ref int s)
    {
            s += 30; // result = 129
            return s;
    }
}
```

For class A, you need a StringBuilder instance to accomplish "helloHi":

```
public Class A
{
    public static void main(string[] args)
    {
        String s = “hello”;
        String w = Changestring(s);
        String x = w; // if you assign s to x, you will just get "hello"
    }

    private string Changestring(string s)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append(s);
        sb.Append(“Hi”);
        return sb.ToString(); // "helloHi"
    }
}
```

CMIIW.

Comment: Got the point. Thanks for the answer. So if I have a string builder in my main method and I pass the same sb to a function **ChangeString** and do operations on sb itself(Append text) without creating new instance of stringbuilder, and not returning any value, will the sb created in main method contain the appended text in the method?

Comment: `sealed` prevents a class from being subclassed, it does not make it immutable. Immutability depends on how a class is implemented.

Answer (score 2):

In c#, all arguments sent to method are passing **by value**, unless they are passed using either the `ref` or `out` keywords.

This includes arguments that are value types, reference types, mutable and immutable types.

When passing a **reference type argument** to a method, what actually happens is that **the *reference* of the argument is passed *by value*.**

This means that the method actually holds a ***new reference*** to the argument passed to it.
So any change to that argument's state will be also reflected when using the reference from outside the method.
However, when assigning a new value to the reference inside the method, it will not reflect on the reference outside the method.

For a better, more extensive explanation, read Jon Skeet's [Parameter passing in C#](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/parameters.html) article.

You can't test this using any *immutable* type, since immutable types, by definition, can't be changed.

You can, however, test this with any mutable type:

```
public static void Main()
{
    var x = new List<int>();
    x.Add(1);
    Add(x, 2);
    Console.WriteLine(x.Count.ToString()); // will print "2";
    AddRef(ref x, 3);
    Console.WriteLine(x.Count.ToString()); // will print "1";
    Add3(x, 1, 2, 3 );
    Console.WriteLine(x.Count.ToString()); // will also print "1";
    Add3Ref(ref x, 1, 2, 3 );
    Console.WriteLine(x.Count.ToString()); // will print "3";
}

static void Add(List<int> list, int value)
{
    // adding an item to the list, thus chaning the state of the list.
    // this will reflect on the list sent to the method, 
    // since a List is a reference type.
    list.Add(value);
}

static void AddRef(ref List<int> list, int value)
{
    list = new List<int>(); // same as the s += “Hi”; in the question
    // Adding the value to the list.
    // Note that this change will reflect on the list passed to the method,
    // since it is passed using the ref keyword.
    list.Add(value);
}


static void Add3(List<int> list, int value1, int value2, int value3)
{
    list = new List<int>(); // same as the s += “Hi”; in the question

    // these values are added to the new list.
    // since the reference to the list was passed by value,
    // it WILL NOT effect the list sent to the method.
    list.Add(value1); 
    list.Add(value2);
    list.Add(value3);
}

static void Add3Ref(ref List<int> list, int value1, int value2, int value3)
{
    list = new List<int>(); // same as the s += “Hi”; in the question
    // these values are added to the new list.
    // since the list was passed by reference,
    // it WILL effect the list sent to the method.
    list.Add(value1);
    list.Add(value2);
    list.Add(value3);
}
```

[You can see for yourself on this fiddle.](https://dotnetfiddle.net/WBmZQA)